# Poke holes in my approach: Insert parent-child-grandchild-etc rows all related with Identity values

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am parsing one flat file that results in a hierarchy of related records 4 levels deep.

I'd like to calculate the next Identity value from each table (using IDENT_CURRENT and IDENT_INCR functions) and then parse the files in memory, assigning and incrementing IDs as I process the file. Lastly I'd just BCP (or other task if I decide to do this in SSIS) the file(s) in, starting with the top of the hierarchy of course.

This will be done during off-hours, and I would be able to lock the tables to assure no inserts could be performed in the meantime

Aside from a lengthy transaction, I don't see any issues with this approach... It does seem a bit too easy though - am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so. SSIS is quick with these sorts of transformations, too, should you choose to use that as your tool.